# cropping image propery from a specific portion using GD library

Tags: php, gd, crop

I am not able to crop the image bellow properly using this code. I am not sure about the problem but some of the jpg are cropped correctly with this code.
For coordinate selection i am using [Image Cropper](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?BEAlLLl9) in front end.

For the image i have attached bellow, cropping doesn't happen according to starting point x and y, and it starts from different position for some images like the one bellow. 
Cropping width and height is ok but starting point is not though i have provided x and y value.

```
$sourceFile = 'test.jpg';
$destinationFile = 'dest/test.jpg';
$jsonData = '{"x": 142, "y":233, "width":372, "height":209}';
$dataCropValue = json_decode($jsonData);

$src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceFile);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($sourceFile);
$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($dataCropValue->width, $dataCropValue->height);
imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0 , $dataCropValue->x , $dataCropValue->y ,     
                   $dataCropValue->width, $dataCropValue->height , 
                   $dataCropValue->width, $dataCropValue->height);
 imagejpeg($dst_img, $destinationFile);
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be that the size you want to crop at is actually larger than the current image? In which case nothing happens...

Comment: Edit your question to include a `var_dump` or `print_r` of `$dataCropValue` and an exact description of the problem. "I am not able to crop this image properly using this code" tells us nothing about _what issues you are facing_.

Comment: I've updated $dataCropValue and added some description @timclutton

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Your code, as posted, works correctly for me with your image. I can only suggest you double-check your incoming json values are really set as you expect them to be.